# How to perform aggregation in two different columns of same table and join in mysql?

Tags: mysql

DB consists of a table named `floorsheet_table` which contains data like this:

```
+-------+--------------+---------------+----------+
| scrip | buyer_broker | seller_broker | quantity |
+-------+--------------+---------------+----------+
| AKPL  |            1 |            34 |       80 |
| AKPL  |            1 |             1 |      100 |
| AKPL  |            34|            56 |     1000 |
| AKPL  |            1 |            40 |      200 |
| AKPL  |            1 |            35 |       50 |
| AKPL  |            1 |            52 |       50 |
| AKPL  |           52 |            56 |      120 |
| AKPL  |            1 |            56 |      140 |
| AKPL  |           17 |            56 |      100 |
| AKPL  |           41 |            56 |      100 |
+-------+--------------+---------------+----------+
```

I want to find sum of quantity by aggregating buyer_broker and seller_broker fields:

- unique buyer_broker and naming `SUM(quantity)` field as 'BOUGHT'. Example:

```
SELECT scrip, buyer_broker AS 'BROKER', SUM(quantity) AS 'BOUGHT' FROM floorsheet_table GROUP BY scrip, buyer_broker;

+-------+--------+--------+
| scrip | BROKER | BOUGHT |
+-------+--------+--------+
| AKPL  |      1 |  21533 |
| AKPL  |     17 |  11540 |
| AKPL  |     41 |  31103 |
| AKPL  |     49 |  43826 |
| AKPL  |     45 |  44402 |
| AKPL  |     54 |  16685 |
| AKPL  |      6 |  12609 |
| AKPL  |      4 |   7220 |
| AKPL  |     38 |  13824 |
| AKPL  |     21 |  20214 |
+-------+--------+--------+
```

- grouping by seller_broker and naming `SUM(quantity)` field as 'SOLD'. Example:

```
SELECT scrip, seller_broker AS 'BROKER', SUM(quantity) AS 'SOLD' FROM floorsheet_table GROUP BY scrip, seller_broker;

+-------+--------+-------+
| scrip | BROKER | SOLD  |
+-------+--------+-------+
| AKPL  |      4 | 59762 |
| AKPL  |     16 | 46460 |
| AKPL  |     58 | 40658 |
| AKPL  |     45 | 38380 |
| AKPL  |     49 | 35361 |
| AKPL  |     38 | 34227 |
| AKPL  |     44 | 33393 |
| AKPL  |     59 | 32817 |
| AKPL  |     56 | 31125 |
| AKPL  |     35 | 30368 |
+-------+--------+-------+
```

But I want these results to show on same table instead. They have `scrip` and `BROKER` as common fields. So new table should look like:

```
+-------+--------+--------+----------+
| scrip | BROKER | BOUGHT |   SOLD   |    
+-------+--------+--------+----------+
```

Furthermore:

- If a broker has only bought and not sold, it should still be shown in the new table with value of `SOLD` as `0`.
- I don't want to create an intermediate table and join them to achieve this.

One of my failed attempt at achieving this was:

```
SELECT b.scrip AS 'SCRIP', b.buyer_broker AS 'BROKER', b.BOUGHT as 'BOUGHT', s.SOLD as 'SOLD' FROM
    SELECT scrip, buyer_broker as 'BROKER', SUM(quantity) AS 'BOUGHT' FROM floorsheet_table AS b GROUP BY b.scrip, b.buyer_broker INNER JOIN
    SELECT scrip, seller_broker as 'BROKER', SUM(quantity) AS 'SOLD' FROM floorsheet_table AS s GROUP BY scrip, seller_broker ON b.buyer_broker=s.seller_broker;
```

This raised error:

```
SELECT is not valid at this position for this server version, expecting '(', WITH
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you need a FULL OUTER JOIN which Mysql doesn't have.

On Big tables this is somewhat slow

> ```
> CREATE TABLE floorsheet_table  (
>   `scrip` VARCHAR(4),
>   `buyer_broker` INTEGER,
>   `seller_broker` INTEGER,
>   `quantity` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO floorsheet_table 
>   (`scrip`, `buyer_broker`, `seller_broker`, `quantity`)
> VALUES
>   ('AKPL', '1', '34', '80'),
>   ('AKPL', '1', '1', '100'),
>   ('AKPL', '34', '56', '1000'),
>   ('AKPL', '1', '40', '200'),
>   ('AKPL', '1', '35', '50'),
>   ('AKPL', '1', '52', '50'),
>   ('AKPL', '52', '56', '120'),
>   ('AKPL', '1', '56', '140'),
>   ('AKPL', '17', '56', '100'),
>   ('AKPL', '41', '56', '100');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT buy1.`scrip`,buy1.`BROKER`,`BOUGHT`,`SOLD`
> FROM
> (SELECT scrip, buyer_broker AS 'BROKER', SUM(quantity) AS 'BOUGHT' FROM floorsheet_table GROUP BY scrip, buyer_broker) buy1
> LEFT JOIN (SELECT scrip, seller_broker AS 'BROKER', SUM(quantity) AS 'SOLD' FROM floorsheet_table GROUP BY scrip, seller_broker) sell1
> ON buy1.`scrip` = sell1.`scrip`  AND  buy1.`BROKER` = sell1.`BROKER`
> UNION
> SELECT sell2.`scrip`,sell2.`BROKER`,`BOUGHT`,`SOLD`
> FROM
> (SELECT scrip, buyer_broker AS 'BROKER', SUM(quantity) AS 'BOUGHT' FROM floorsheet_table GROUP BY scrip, buyer_broker) buy2
> RIGHT  JOIN (SELECT scrip, seller_broker AS 'BROKER', SUM(quantity) AS 'SOLD' FROM floorsheet_table GROUP BY scrip, seller_broker) sell2
> ON buy2.`scrip` = sell2.`scrip`  AND  buy2.`BROKER` = sell2.`BROKER`
> ```

> ```
> scrip | BROKER | BOUGHT | SOLD
> :---- | -----: | -----: | ---:
> AKPL  |      1 |    620 |  100
> AKPL  |     34 |   1000 |   80
> AKPL  |     52 |    120 |   50
> AKPL  |     17 |    100 | null
> AKPL  |     41 |    100 | null
> AKPL  |     56 |   null | 1460
> AKPL  |     40 |   null |  200
> AKPL  |     35 |   null |   50
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2db363d9cdf4340a4b5982db6e66704e)*